# UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct

Tags: arrays, struct, solidity, smartcontracts

I want to create the array variables that fill with the struct that I've created and unfortunately, I got the error. The error said that:

UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct Test.IncrementalPrice memory[2] memory to storage not yet supported.

Does anybody know what's wrong and how to fix this?

```
   contract Test {

     struct IncrementalPrice{
        uint256 prices;
        uint256 threshold;
     }

     IncrementalPrice[] price = [
        IncrementalPrice(0, 1000),
        IncrementalPrice(0.01 ether, 2000)
     ];
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey first of all your make sure you code run in function or constructors

```
function setData() public {
  IncrementalPrice[] price = [
    IncrementalPrice(0, 1000),
    IncrementalPrice(0.01, 2000)
 ];
```

}

and you define your price var as int 256 so change

```
IncrementalPrice(0.01 ether, 2000)
```

to

```
IncrementalPrice(0.01, 2000)
```

Second, check your solidity version, solidity is a new language and changes very quickly, make sure you are using the latest version.